# rubyのFileクラス拡張について

Tags: ruby

rubyのFileクラスを拡張したいのですがうまくいきません。

rubyのバージョンは2.0.0p648を使用しております。
http://qiita.com/umanoda/items/33613b94ccabf7b1f851
こちらの記事を参考に試しました。
'extend'が表示されるようにしたいのですが、openメソッドは通常の動作を返してしまいます。

どなたかご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

```
class File
  alias_method :__open__, :open

  def open()
    'extend'
  end
end

p File.open('test.txt')
#<File:test.txt>
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: パッケージ名の修飾とシグネチャを合わせる必要がありますので、`def open()` を `def File.open(*args)` とします。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4):

クラスメソッドを上書きするので、インスタンスメソッドではなくクラスメソッドを定義することになるかと思います。

```
class File
  class << self
    alias_method :__open__, :open
  end

  def self.open(*args)
    'extend'
  end
end

p File.open('test.txt')
```

Comment: 上記の方法で解決でしました。
大変参考になります。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: `class << self`の中で`def open`すればいいと思うのですが、外に出している理由は何かあるのでしょうか

Comment: 「インスタンスメソッド定義ではなくクラスメソッド定義」というのが回答の中心メッセージなので、クラスメソッドの基本的な定義方法を明示的に使いました。